# how to make rollup sequencer decentralized?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, evm, rollups

I know the logic to make a centralised sequencer for a blockchain rollup ( layer 2 solution ) , but i have no idea on how to make the sequencer decetralised. so that no one central authority will get full access to send data of layer-2 to layer-1 blockchain ?